# STARTUP2 mode - command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{}

Tags: index, mongodb, data-synchronization, startup, mongodb-3.2

MongoDB 3.2.8 is in STARTUP2 mode building indexes at the moment. A replicaset with 3 nodes.

```
2016-08-15T08:11:19.385+0200 I -        [rsSync]   Index Build: 387200/2273552 17%
2016-08-15T08:11:19.425+0200 I COMMAND  [conn17] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "etrer", configVersion: 8, from: "hostname", fromId: 0, term: 17 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:485 locks:{} protocol:op_command 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:19.492+0200 I COMMAND  [conn146] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:19.504+0200 I COMMAND  [conn145] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 8ms
2016-08-15T08:11:20.395+0200 I COMMAND  [conn158] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 3ms
2016-08-15T08:11:21.428+0200 I COMMAND  [conn17] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "sfsfsf", configVersion: 8, from: "hostname", fromId: 0, term: 17 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:485 locks:{} protocol:op_command 2ms
2016-08-15T08:11:22.242+0200 I -        [rsSync]   Index Build: 387700/2273552 17%
2016-08-15T08:11:22.460+0200 I COMMAND  [conn1670] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "srgewfef", configVersion: 8, from: "hostname", fromId: 2, term: 17 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:485 locks:{} protocol:op_command 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:22.738+0200 I COMMAND  [conn1205] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 4ms
2016-08-15T08:11:23.053+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2969] command admin.$cmd command: serverStatus { serverStatus: 1, locks: false, recordStats: false } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:18641 locks:{} protocol:op_query 5ms
2016-08-15T08:11:23.750+0200 I COMMAND  [conn1098] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 2ms
2016-08-15T08:11:23.814+0200 I COMMAND  [conn1113] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:23.836+0200 I COMMAND  [conn747] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 3ms
2016-08-15T08:11:23.940+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2197] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:24.376+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2784] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:24.518+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2648] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 5ms
2016-08-15T08:11:25.067+0200 I COMMAND  [conn1425] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:25.316+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2848] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 2ms
2016-08-15T08:11:25.403+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2693] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 2ms
2016-08-15T08:11:25.472+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2908] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1ms
2016-08-15T08:11:25.501+0200 I -        [rsSync]   Index Build: 388400/2273552 17%
2016-08-15T08:11:25.631+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2896] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 5ms
```

What does the this message (every second, 64680 times in less than one day) mean?

```
 COMMAND  [conn747] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:644 locks:{} protocol:op_query 2ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB drivers and clients use the [`isMaster` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/) to describe the current role of a `mongod` instance, monitor round trip time, and verify replica set configuration/status (if applicable).

Frequent `isMaster` commands are expected behaviour, although the occurrence will vary depending on how many clients/drivers you have connected as well as the driver versions.

For more information you might be interested in the [Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM) specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst) which details the behaviour for officially supported MongoDB drivers.